# How do we know that the Frobenius norm is not subordinate to a vector norm?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-norms

In a quiz

The following statement was said to be False:
"The Frobenius norm is a matrix norm subordinate to (or induced by) a vector norm"

At the time of writing, I can't see why/how we know this to be False. How do we know that there isn't some vector norm to which the Frobenius norm is subordinate?

the operational definition of subordinate norm being:

"Given a vector norm $||\cdot||$, the corresponding subordinate matrix norm is defined by
$$||A||= \max_{x \not =0} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$$"

Comment: It is when the matrix is $1\times1$. For larger-sized matrices, consider $\|I\|_F$.

Comment: I actually do not understand this question. Induced by a vector norm on what? What does "induced by" mean?

Comment: If a norm is induced, the norm of the identity matrix must be $1.$   What is the Frobenuis norm of the identity matrix?

Comment: @Will So "induced by a vector norm" signifies the operator norm on matrices? *shrug*

Comment: @Ted  yes.  I believe Wikipedia uses the phrase.

Comment: @Will I've never encountered this vagueness before. I mean, I guess it's clear in the context of the OP's course, but you and I know that $GL(n)$ may have representations other than the $n$-dimensional one.

Comment: @Ted   I first heard of it in an undergrad operations research/numerical methods type course. There is a little book by Householder, Kahan directed me to that when I had a question about the area. https://store.doverpublications.com/0486449726.html

Comment: Granted. I presume the OP's course made the context totally explicit.

Comment: Indeed, I've included the definition of subordinate being used in the course

Comment: @Ted For what it's worth, this terminology is also used by Horn and Johnson in their texts